# How do I access the AWS PHP SDK on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, ec2-api-tools

I have gotten to know that the AWS SDK comes with the default operating system installed on AWS EC2 when provisioned via Elastic Beanstalk.

I would like to know if I can access the PHP version of the SDK.
Or does it need to be installed separately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Install it using `phar` or `composer` , Please Refer [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html) for this:

**To use Composer with the AWS SDK for PHP:**

1. Open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where your
   project is stored. Composer is installed on a per-project basis.
2. Download and install Composer in your project directory. If you have
   curl installed, you can use the following command:

   `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
3. Create a file at the root level of your project called composer.json
   and add the following dependency for the AWS PHP SDK:

   `{
       "require": {
           "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
       }
   }`
4. Install the dependencies by running Composer's `install` command:

   `php composer.phar install`

This will create a vendor directory in your project with the required libraries and an autoloader script used to load them for your project.

5. Require Composer's autoloader by adding the following line to your
   code's bootstrap process (typically in `index.php`):

   `require '/path/to/sdk/vendor/autoload.php';`

Your code is now ready to use the AWS SDK for PHP!